# Positioning problems in Firefox? position:relative for a display:table element

Tags: css, html, firefox, position

i'm experiencing the weirdest positioning problem that appears only in firefox.

**My HTML:**

```
<article id="one" class="layer"></article>
<article id="two" class="layer"></article>
<article id="three" class="layer">
   <div class="left"></div>
   <div class="right"></div>
</article>
```

**My CSS:**

```
html, body {
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

article.layer {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

article .left, article .right {
  position:absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height:100%;
  display:table;
}

article .left { left: 0; top: 0; }
article .right { left: 50%; top: 0; }
```

So each article is set to `display:table` and 100% width and 100% height. The body and html is also 100% wide and high. Therefore each article is exactly the size of the current browserwindow.

Notice that each `article.layer` is set to `position:relative`.

The latest article has two `div`s in it positioned `absolute` so one is positioned to the left and one to the right.

This works fine in all browsers, except in Firefox. In Firefox the `div.left` and `div.right` of the last article are shown on top and overlay the first article …

Here is a live demo: http://jsbin.com/ubulot/edit#preview
Test it in Firefox and you see the problem. I have FF 9.0.1 installed on my Mac.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you change `display:table` to `display:block` throughout, it renders fine as you can see [here](http://jsbin.com/ubulot/2/edit#preview). Is there a reason you're using `display:table`?

Comment: Tested on Firefox 3.6 on Ubuntu.

Comment: You can also remove `position:absolute` and change `display:table` to `display:table-cell` to achieve the same effect. [Example here](http://jsbin.com/ubulot/3/edit#preview).

Answer (score 13):

I'm using display:table myself. It's a work-around for certain layout issues that display: block fails to sufficiently deal with. The rationale is lengthy and I'm not going into it here.

This is a consequence of the current HTML 4/5 specification not defining certain behaviors with regards to the "display: table{-x};" and positioning.

From the book "Everything You Know About CSS Is Wrong" BY Rachel Andrew & Kevin Yank:

> A common practice when dealing with positioning within a block element
>   is to create a new positioning context by setting the position
>   property of the block element to relative. This allows us to position
>   elements within the block, relative to its top, right, bottom, or
>   left. However, when setting position: relative; on an element that
>   also has a table-related display value specified, the positioning is
>   ignored. This behavior has previously been documented by Alastair
>   Campbell, who points out in his article that the CSS 2.1 spec is not
>   clear on what browsers should do when an element displaying as a table
>   element is relatively positioned:
>
> The effect of position: relative on table-row-group,
>   table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-row, table-columngroup,
>   table-column, table-cell, and table-captionelements is undefined.
>
> This behavior is, in my opinion, the biggest problem with using CSS tables
>   for layout...

Apparently Mozilla simply ignores any attempt to establish a positioning context using CSS table elements.

The same reference continues with two suggestions:

> There’s no straightforward approach to fixing this problem using CSS tables, but we can take one of two simple approaches to provide a positioning context: add a positioned child block element to the cell, or wrap the table in a positioned element.

There is no elegant solution to this one. It requires a case-by-case evaluation of the issue and a tailored workaround. :(

In your case you might as well leave off the "position: relative" out of your "Layer" class. It's meaningless to Firefox.

Since you've created the "Layer" class as a table, simple make each of the s in the last instance "display: table-cell;".

so your CSS can be done thus:

```
.Layer:last-of-type > div
{
display: table-cell;
/* Other formatting here. */
}
```

Comment: This is by far the best answer. So many people just say "use display: block", but this actually describes why the problem exists. Thank you!