# CSS Positioning Absolute within table cells not working in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, position, positioning

I cannot figure out this positioning problem in Firefox. It doesn't seem to follow the absolute positioning rule. Is there something I'm doing that shouldn't be done, but some browesers handle it and some don't?

**JS Fiddle:**

Original - http://jsfiddle.net/g9qzh/

Updated - http://jsfiddle.net/g9qzh/2/

Works in IE, Chrome, Safari, Opera

Here's the actual code. Let me know if I'm not following some kind of standard I don't know about.

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="three">Three</div>
            <div id="two">Two</div>
        </td>
    <tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="three">Three</div>
            <div id="two">Two</div>
        </td>
    <tr>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```css
#two {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
}
td {
   position: relative;
}
```

​My only clue is that there is some other value that I should assign to `td` that would cause it to work. Some other stackoverflow questions have mentioned Firefox misbehaving with this, but I haven't been able to find an answer. I tried assigning both top and left values of zero, but FF won't budge.
​

Comment: this is working in FF 12.0 for me. "Two" is overlapping "Three" - but its still wrong, refer to my answer

Comment: Each "two" should be overlapping it's own "three" I'm not sure if you were just seeing both "two" overlapping the same three

Comment: This has been recorded as a bug 14 years ago! https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35168 Read this useful article http://davidwalsh.name/table-cell-position-absolute

Comment: As of firefox 32 absolute positioning of elements within table cells seems to work fine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change ID's to classes and also displaying it as blocks fixes it:

http://jsfiddle.net/GchWZ/

It is better and more "proper" to user an inner div though as quoted from this stack overflow post: [Does Firefox support position: relative on table elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148041/does-firefox-support-position-relative-on-table-elements)

```
<td>
  <div style="position:relative">
      This will be positioned normally
      <div style="position:absolute; top:5px; left:5px;">
           This will be positioned at 5,5 relative to the cell
      </div>
  </div>
</td>
```

Comment: That worked! Great, now how did you know to do that? Is it something I should read up about (I don't really know the proper use of `display`) or is it something that is just a "fix" for Firefox or should it be a standard operating procedure whenever doing this in the future?

Comment: I remember reading a long time ago something about how firefox handles td's differently. I'll try to find the article.

Comment: Yeah, `display:block` was a temporary solution, because now that I tried to expand it a bit more and required `display:block-inline` it also broke in Firefox, but still worked in every other browser.

Comment: Actually now `diplay:inline-block` worked. I'm going to select your answer as it required online an extra line of CSS and not a lot more html.

Answer (score 1):

You are using IDs

IDs are unique. Use Classes if you want to reuse a style assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="three">Three</div>
            <div id="two">Two</div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="three">Three</div>
            <div id="two">Two</div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

and for css:

```
#two {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
}

#wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from how FF renders tables. If you set your TDs to `display:inline-block;` it should display correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the duplicate `ID` issue noted by Brandt, assigning [positioning to table cells is dodgy at best](http://css-tricks.com/absolutely-position-element-within-a-table-cell/) - I'm surprised it works in any browsers. If you must use a table, wrap the elements you want to position in a div and assign the wrapper div `position: relative`:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div id="three">Three</div>
            <div id="two">Two</div>
        </div>
        </td>
    <tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```css
#two {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
}
.wrapper {
   position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to position stuff at the top *and* bottom of a cell, also in Firefox, I made it work doing the following mix of CSS and (unfortunately) jQuery.

1. Use a wrapper div (div.inner) inside your td which has position=relative style in the td. Inside the wrapper I added 2 divs which are to be positioned at the top and bottom of the cell.
   [image]
2. Positioning at the top (class=interval-start) is for free, via CSS positioning.
3. Positioning the div.interval-end at the bottom is done via script, which adds the styling shown in the picture. With variable td-heights and the wrapper div being 0-height by default, you need a way to tell the element how far it should go to the bottom. The script is as follows:

   ```
           $("table .inner .interval-end").each(function () {
               $(this).css({top: ($(this).parent().parent().height() - 10) + "px"})
           }).show()
   ```
4. I initially made the div.interval-end invisible, set the 'top' style, and then made it visible via jQuery show().

Hope this helps anybody trying to achieve the same. Let me know if there are better methods out there, specially if these methods do not require scripting. BTW: I tried setting the height style of the wrapper div.inner, but it messes with the table layout in Firefox.

Answer (score -1):

There are legitimate reasons to use CSS display: table styling. It eliminates issues that display: block and display: inline-block do not address. These reasons occupy an entire chapter of a book on CSS styling so I won't go into them here. That same book also describes the problem of positioning within items with that display type. CSS 2.1 specs simply don't address the issue and Mozilla has chosen a course that ignores attempts to create a positioning context with those elements. CSS-table positioning is well established, mature methodology, and not "dodgy" - it just takes understanding of its limits - just like any other CSS element. For liquid layouts and other layouts where element size is variable or unknown it's indispensable for vertical spacing and positioning.

One suggestion in this thread has been presented - create a div within the "table-cell" element set to position: relative and use that for the positioning context. The other method is to embed another CSS table within that cell and use it to position elements within a grid. The third method is to wrap your CSS table within another item that creates a positioning context.

Comment: I'm a bit late getting back to this, but I find myself surprised with the down vote. Why? I gave a rather detail response on this topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951993/positioning-problems-in-firefox-positionrelative-for-a-displaytable-element/11353364#11353364

..and received a major up vote and "Best Answer" for my reply. I use CSS Tables for horizontal menu positioning and as a solution to the problem of "Stick Footers" without recourse to absolute dimensions (Oh, Mr. User? You need to make your display be THIS size for it to look right...) or JavaScript.