# position a <span> at the bottom of a <td> table cell

Tags: css, css-position, html-table, html

I am trying to get a `<span>` to sit at the bottom of a fixed-height `<td>`, however it does not seem to be working.

I am developing in Firefox using Firebug and this is my markup and CSS.

I have read other posts stating that the `td` height needs to be fixed, well I have done that, however I am still having the same problem. How can I position the span at the bottom of the td?

```
<td class="details_amount">
  <span class="item_total_price">
    £<span id="amount_99201100099">49</span>
  </span>
  <br>
  <span class="person_price">£5</span>
</td>

td {
    height: 55px;
    padding-top: 1.8em;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.item_total_price {
    height: 100%;
}

.person_price {
    bottom: 0;
    position: relative;
}
```

[image: How it looks in Firefox]

Comment: Put `position:relative` to `td` and `position:absolute;bottom:0;` to `.person_price `.

Comment: @Vucko Thanks, I tried that. But it doesn't work - i'm clearly missing something obvious but not sure what...

Comment: Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Eg3j3/)?

Comment: @Vucko Oh. Did you create that Fiddle in Chrome? Check out my screenshot from Firefox - http://i.stack.imgur.com/bzvs7.png - it sinks it to the bottom of the page. I have looked at your Fiddle on Chrome and it works as expected though. Why would FF exhibit this behaviour?

Comment: @Vucko I Think i've found the solution - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256004/firefox-issue-with-displayabsolute-in-a-table-cell i.e. `display: block` on the `td`.

Comment: Yes, it seems that FF has problems - [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11021308/css-positioning-absolute-within-table-cells-not-working-in-firefox).

Comment: Use `display:inline-block` if you have more then one `td` and that will suit. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need `position:absolute` not `position: relative` for `.person_price`:

```
.person_price {
   position: absolute;
   bottom:0;
   left:0;
}
```

And also make his parent `relative`:

```
td {
  position:relative;
}
```

Comment: Hmmm...I tried this initally before I posted, but it wasn't working for me. It positions it at the bottom of the page and that is _with_ the relative positioning attached to the `td`.

Comment: Thanks for this, it does indeed work - it just needed a `display: block` on the `td` for support on Firefox. I've made an edit to the post.

Answer (score 0):

absolute, not relative.

```
.person_price {
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: This alone would position it at the bottom of the page, not the table cell.